# getJSON and OAuth Token

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oauth, getjson

I'm working on a script that uses jQuery (getJSON) to pullback values from a PHP page. The PHP page correctly displays the encoded object with the correct keys and values, with the values being retrieved from the `$_SESSION` variable. However when the javascript attempts to access this page, the object is retrieved, but only the keys are intact with the values being replaced with `null`. The values that are returning `null` are retrieved from the `$_SESSION`, whereas any values that are manually added are correctly returning. Is this something that can be avoided/fixed? Would it make more sense to store the access tokens in cookies rather than sessions?

Code examples:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $token = $_SESSION['token'] -> access_token;

  $information = [
     "media_token" => $token,
     "test" => "testing"
     ]; 

  print json_encode($information); //when page is directly accessed, 
                                   //returns correct information
?>
```

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON('oauth.php', function (data){
            console.log(data); // media_token: null
                               // test: testing
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I was accessing the page that contained the JS using a non-www page, whereas adding www fixed the problem. Not sure why but clearly this changed if the page could access the $_SESSION or not. If anyone could explain why this is the case that'd be great, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

***Try this code it will help you***

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('oauth.php', function (data){
            console.log(data); // media_token: null
                               // test: testing
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="title">
    <h2>PRESS</h2>
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**oauth.php file**

```
 session_start();
  $_SESSION['token']="Hello1212";
  $token = $_SESSION['token'];// -> access_token;

  $information = array(
    "media_token" => $token,
    "test" => "testing"
);

  print json_encode($information); //when page is directly accessed, 
                                   //returns correct information
```

Comment: Token can be sent through the javascript 'oauth.php?token=value'. It will help you to get the value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the value $_SESSION['token'] is certainly set as when directly accessing oauth.php the resulting output looks like:
`{"token":"283Eeh.380dc4hgpp74d0d8c939d12oll","test":"testing"}`

but the issue remains that when $.getJSON accesses the page, `media_token` is returned as `null`, yet key `test` and value `testing` are returned...

Comment: i have got the values in the page :  Object { media_token="Hello1212", test="testing"}

Comment: PHP locks the access to the session file during the duration of an ajax call to make sure the data isn't corrupted across connections, so you have to use session_write_close() to finalize the writing to get a response from the second ajax call.